# Which PHP file taking so mysql resources on server?

Tags: php, mysql, centos

one of the php file is using so much mysql memory usage, how can i find out which php file is taking so much load or taking so much execution time ? any command for terminal ? need help

Comment: In linux, there is a way you can check for the resources usage, you could type top in terminal, but I doubt it would show which file. Can you check on website itself, like which page is taking longer time than usual?

Comment: Yes I have checked using top command, it provide me the processes, but how can i direct find out like which php file is running on runtime. top command is only provide me the processes.

Comment: I have also detail checked my website, but not figured out which problem i am facing.

Comment: So when you access your website, which page is loading longer than usual? Your issue here could be that the mysql connection is not closed or it could be a wrong query that caused the loop not ending or taking longer time. This is just my guess.

Comment: Thanks for reply iCezz, I am 100% agree with this. Actually i am facing problem like suddenly my Server mysql memory usage high and also load average and after that memory usage increase to 100%. I am still not able to find out which php file is taking so much mysql resources, it happens to me once in a day and server down with in 4 to 8 minutes (may be some one is attacking). I am first looking which php file is taking so much load time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in mysql terminal command:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

[SHOW PROCESSLIST Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-processlist.html)